# Open an excel file without especifying name

Tags: excel, vba

I've build a macro on an separate excel that manipulates a source workbook and creates another with the new data, the source it's expected to be in `srcFolder` and the outcome file on `outFolder`.

Currently I'm calling the file this way:

```
Set srcBk = Application.Workbooks.Open("sourceBook.xlsm")
```

And the output file is out in the same folder the macro is on. What i can't make work it's making the macro the file and folder "name proof". Ideally users put the file in the folder and run the macro without caring about the name or file extension (it will always be .xls, .cls, etc files) and also drag the macro folder (containing both in and out folders) within their pc's but calling the file with `*` and setting one folder only it's not working, it doesn't find the file.

```
Set srcBk= Application.Workbooks.Open("\srcFolder\*.*")

Set srcBk = Application.Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\srcFolder\*.*")
```

Edit: Attempt with `Application.FileDialog`

```
Dim bkDir As Office.FileDialog
Dim srcBk As Workbook
Set bkDir = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With bkDir
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Seleccione archivo fuente:"
        .Filters.Clear
        If .Show = True Then
            bkDir = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))
            Set srcBK = Application.Workbooks.Open(bkDir)
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: use `Dir` function to loop through the files in the folder and you can filter as well

Comment: Or you can use the [Application.FileDialog property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog) to let the user select a specific file.

Comment: I've used both `FileDialog` and `Dir` inside the function but I get an error 91 on line `srcBk = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))`.

Comment: @AbdónAraya we cannot help if we don't see your code. [Edit] your question and add the code please.

Comment: Added the new code. Thanks.

Comment: @AbdónAraya you don't need `Dir` if you use the `FileDialog` to select a file. Throw out `bkDir = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))` and use `Application.Workbooks.Open(bkDir.SelectedItems(1))`

Comment: It worked! Thank you!